# How to inspect POST body in nginx (HttpLuaModule)

Tags: post, nginx, lua

My goal is to inspect a body of the POST request and compare it to some list of key-value pairs on nginx. In my situation POST requests will always be in JSON format. Each request will contain a `key:value` pair like this: `"transaction":"12345"` or `"transaction":"098765"`. Mean the key "transaction" will always be there and value will change some time. 
I was thinking to use [lua-nginx-module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule) to inspect a post body and than compare it with key-value from let's say `memcached`.
I don't have any code to show yet, but I will try to update a question, some time soon. I was wondering if someone could help me get started, with this or show how it can be done.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't have a specific question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are various ways to inspect the POST requesty body in ngx_lua, depending on your needs:

1. Fully buffered way: use [ngx.req.read_body](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#ngx.req.read_body), [ngx.req.get_body_data](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#ngx.req.get_body_data), and [ngx.req.get_body_file](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#ngx.req.get_body_file).
2. Streaming processing way: use [ngx.req.socket](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#ngx.req.socket) to read and process the request body stream in chunks.

Comment: and other methods like PUT and DELETE ?

Answer (score 9):

This is what I did:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        location /api/setdata {           
            lua_need_request_body on;
            content_by_lua_file template/content.lua;
        }       
    }
```

**template/content.lua:**

```
function processRequest()
    ngx.req.read_body()
    local request_body = ngx.req.get_body_data()  
    ngx.say(request_body)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the following would suffice:

```
ngx.req.read_body()
local request_body = ngx.req.get_body_data()
```

There's no need to use the `lua_need_request_body on;` directive as well, since it does the same thing as `ngx.req.read_body()`.